# lowering lighttpd response time

Tags: lighttpd

Been using Pingdom to track the response time of some of my sites.  A couple are using Apache, and a couple are using lighttpd.  The response times for domains on lighttpd are hovering around 1300-1700ms.  The only configurations I have loaded are vhosts and fastcgi (for php).

The box is a 1.7GHz Celeron with 2GB of RAM (fairly maxed, unfortunately).

Is there any way to lower the response time?

**EDIT**: Response time for Apache seems to be in the range of 2-3000ms.  Fairly consistently in that range.

**EDIT 2**: After checking Pingdom again, the response times for Lighttpd over the past 7 days are 2957ms, and Apache is 1384ms.  This seems very backwards to me.

Comment: Are you using gzip compression already?

Comment: What would gzip compression get me for response time?

Comment: My 2c: I don't think gzip would boost response time.

Comment: You give the response times for lighttpd, but not for Apache. Seems like relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is simple answer to this, but there are several configuration changes you can try:

1. Disabling the TCP options
2. Enable stat caching - server.stat-cache-engine
3. Recompile to disable support for large files
4. See if your box supports the sendfile() network handler, which serves files faster by pushing them directly to the network card

I picked these as the most likely (IMHO) to boost response time from the tuning guide from lighttpd:
[http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:Performance]